# How can I work with my friend on the same Unity project at the same time?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I started working with Unity a few weeks ago, and today I created a new project, but can I work on it with a friend at the same time? If there's a method, can you explain it to me? I tried to use Unity collaborate, but it didn't work (maybe because I didn't know how to use it properly).

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unity collaborate is pretty bad. Try using git. [github.com](https://github.com) is a very good provider and there are plenty of tutorials

Comment: Whilst Git is fine for white-collar work, it should never be used in the gaming industry considering its dreadful support for large files, even with the _after-the-fact_ Git LFS feature.  [Use _Perforce_ instead.  It's **free** for up to 5 users](https://www.perforce.com/products/helix-core/free-version-control)